# Деплой одностраничного сайта собранный на Webpack

Tags: github-pages

Можно ли загрузить сайт собранный с помощю **Webpack** на **Github Pages**. Я пробовал но сайт не отображается. Я поискал ответ в интернете но не нашёл ответа на этот вопрос.

Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно. Для более подробного ответа надо подробней описать что вы делаете и что именно не работает. Лучше вместе со ссылкой на репозиторий

Comment: Это простая вёрстка. 

Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/KhasanAlimov/Cats-shop/tree/master

Comment: https://khasanalimov.github.io/Cats-shop/dist/ работает. Если надо что бы открывалась в корне посмотрите настройки gh-pages

Comment: Я пробовал по ковырятся в настройках gh-pages, но без результатов.
Ссылка на сайт в gh-pages: https://khasanalimov.github.io/Cats-shop/
Выводится только текст из файла Readme.md

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site вот тут пункт 5 не работает?

Comment: Это я уже сделал. Есть ещё какие то варианты для решения этого вопроса?

Comment: Покажите что вы там сделали

Comment: Вы хотите посмотреть скриншот настроек gh-pages?

Comment: Ну, хотя бы так

Comment: добавил изображение

Comment: Для github pages фактически нет способа брать корень сайта не из корня репозитория или директории docs (кнопка выбора директории - рядом с кнопкой выбора ветки, там где у вас на скриншоте выбрано `/ (root)`)

Comment: Ну так собирайте не в dist, а в docs

Comment: Спасибо Алексей что помогли мне! Я с docs пробовал в начале но и это не помогало. Я смог решить этот вопрос другим путём. Установив плагин gh-pages.
Добавил в npm scrips новую команду  **"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"**.